# Strange redirecting problem when attempting to login using curl

Tags: php

Trying to login using curl on this site: http://www.indianvideogamer.com.

This is my complete script:

```
        $ref = "http://www.indianvideogamer.com/" ;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.indianvideogamer.com/forums/index.php?app=core&amp;module=global&amp;section=login&amp;do=process") ;       // Target site
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "C:/cookie2-techenclave.txt");             
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "C:/cookie2-techenclave.txt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, CURL_TIMEOUT);    // Timeout
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, WEBBOT_NAME); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "referer=http://www.indianvideogamer.com/forums/index.php&username=cute.bandar&password=mypass");

      //  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);     // Follow redirects
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 4);             // Limit redirections to four
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);     // Return in string  


        $webpage['FILE'] = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
         echo $webpage['FILE'] ;
```

the result of running this script on localhost/script.php is that instead of echoing the page it redirects to http://www.localhost/script.php . Why ?

Comment: Is the curl doing the redirect, or hitting that script on your server redirects your browser?

Comment: Most likely it's the webserver itself doing the redirect, not your script. There's nothing in the script that would redirect localhost->www.localhost, but a rewrite rule or some such on the webserver very likely is.

Answer (score 1):

I admit it's not an obvious one.

But finally I made it working. I skipped the URL encoding of ampersand signs in the URL argument. So my line was:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.indianvideogamer.com/forums/index.php?app=core&module=global&section=login&do=process") ;
```

BTW, are you sure it's the whole script? My PHP complains about lack of definition of `CURL_TIMEOUT` and `WEBBOT_NAME`, but that doesn't seem to affect the login.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

This will follow redirects.

Comment: what do you get inside the webpage variable ?